# set up a carthage/cocoapod project to distribute multiple dependencies

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, carthage

Sorry if these questions are basic/dumb.  I haven't had to do any framework setup stuff in the past.  I've just contributed to projects in the past. I want to distribute different parts of an SDK with Cocoapods and Carthage.  For example,

```
github "MyOrg/Core" -> Has interfaces I want to use in SmallerModule.
github "MyOrg/SmallerModule" -> Has third party dependencies I do not own
```

Are there general rules on how to set this up?  My Core project would have interfaces that SmallerModule needs access to.  Should SmallerModule be a part of the Core project or should they be separate Xcode projects?

Secondly, if it is a separate project, how does SmallerModule have access to the interfaces in Core? Do I need to include it as a dependency in SmallerModule? If so, wouldn't Core be duplicated if someone tried to pull in both Core and SmallerModule since Core is a dependency for SmallerModule?

Comment: are `Core` and `SmallerModule` closed source or open source?

Comment: @AndreaMugnaini Open Source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should SmallerModule be a part of the Core project or should they be separate Xcode projects

I guess it depends by the granularity of what you need to be exposed. `SmallerModule` might be separated or merged inside `Core`, remember that once you expose it, it's quite complicate coming back, eg: you might generate dependencies to other projects.

> Secondly, if it is a separate project, how does SmallerModule have access to the interfaces in Core?

If you split the projects, `SmallerModule` will easily have the access to the interfaces of the `Core` dynamic framework, the thing you must do first is generate such framework.

> Do I need to include it as a dependency in SmallerModule

eg: if you use `Carthage` as dependency manager, you should create a `Cartfile` inside the project `SmallerModule` containing this line:

`github "MyOrg/Core"`

then on `SmallerModule` “Build Phases” settings tab, click the “+” icon and choose “New Run Script Phase”, add the following contents to the script area below the shell:

`/usr/local/bin/carthage copy-frameworks`

Add the paths to the frameworks you want to use under “Input Files”, e.g.:

`$(SRCROOT)/Carthage/Build/iOS/Core.framework`

Add the paths to the copied frameworks to the “Output Files”, e.g.:

`$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/$(FRAMEWORKS_FOLDER_PATH)/Core.framework`

then after resolving the dependency:

`carthage update`

You will find `Core.framework` inside the folder `./Carthage/build/iOS/` so you may drag and drop such framework inside your `SmallerModule` to be able to compile it.

> wouldn't Core be duplicated if someone tried to pull in both Core and SmallerModule since Core is a dependency for SmallerModule

Since you'll be using a dependency manager (eg: `Carthage`), it won't be a problem. All the dependencies will be resolved (if they link the same version eg: `tag x.y.z`) by the dependency manager itself during the resolution process (`carthage update`).

Note that if `SuperSmallerModule` has to bind your `SmallerModule`, then assuming everything is fine, must create a `Cartfile` with:

`github "MyOrg/SmallerModule"`

and follow the same process, also explained [here](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage#getting-started).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. Could you clarify "SmallerModule might be separated or merged inside Core, remember that once you expose it, it's quite complicate coming back, eg: you might generate dependencies to other unknown projects."? Keeping it as part of two separate modules makes sense using Carthage as you outlined. By doing it this way, does it prevent any third party who wants to consume Core and SmallerModule with Cocoapods if I use Carthage internally myself for SmallerModule depending on Core?

Comment: Premise that I don't know the complexity of your projects and what you eventually need to expose. `SmallerModule` might be a separated framework (following above steps) or merged inside `Core`, in this case you would have to maintain (tag/release/api compatibility and so on...) just one framework (`Core`). It's up to you to decide if having 1 or 2 frameworks to maintain. By the way, in theory, there shouldn't be any conflict between Cocoapods and Carthage, many frameworks provide kind of integration for both dependency managers. Eg: https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire